# Java applets which layout suitable for this interface?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, layout-manager

Which is the most suitable layout for this interface? I have tried `FlowLayout`, but can't get the <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> button place in the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this out on a JFrame and you can do the same in your applet.

Create a Grid of One row two columns.
 Create a Box Layout on the second Panel with Page Axis and then ensure you have vertical glues with button in center. 
 Create a Grid of 3x3 and add buttons.

Code sample:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)

    {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText(i+"");
        leftPanel.add(button);
    }
    frame.add(leftPanel);
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
     BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
     rightPanel.setLayout(layout);

     JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
         button.setAlignmentX(
     Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
     rightPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue()); //Ensure this order
     rightPanel.add(button);
     rightPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());


    frame.add(rightPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Change JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3)); to  JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 10,10)); //to add space.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com), it is very easy to use and it always handles, what I am throwing at it.

In this case, I would create two panels. The first panel has a "wrap 3" constraint as a parameter for the miglayout constructor, the second only has one button, which is added with a "alignx center, aligny center" constraint.

Here is an example:

```
public class TestApplet extends JApplet{

@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();
    setSize(400, 300);
    setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets 0"));

    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 3"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        leftPanel.add(new JButton(""+i));
    }
    add(leftPanel);

    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    rightPanel.add(new JButton("submit"), "alignx center, aligny center");
    add(rightPanel);


}   
}
```

[image]

You only have to sort the numbers on the buttons by your needs.

Answer (score 1):

- First Grid Layout with two columns.
- in first column add panal1 and in second add submit with `BorderLayout.CENTER`.
- In that panal1 you can use 3x3 grid layout.

Comment: BorderLayout.CENTER will occupy full second Panel.